# Can someone explain the creeping flow approximation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity, navier-stokes

Hello I’m a HS student so I apologize if my knowledge isn’t adequate enough, or if you have to dumb down concepts for me.

I’m writing an IB extended essay, and right now I’m trying to understand creeping flow. I think I understand the general gist of it. When the reynolds number is much smaller than one because the inertial drag forces are negligible compared to the viscous forces, thus causing creeping flow where there are a lack of eddies.

What I can’t seem to wrap my head around is the simplified NSE (where: Eu = 1/Re…), how was this equation derived, and what does it even mean? I probably just don’t have a good grasp of the NSE, and the resources out there are quite confusing, so if someone could explain this to me that would help alot.

Thanks

Comment: The first step is to reduce the NS equations to dimensionless form, right?  What we are saying is that the mass times acceleration terms in the NS equations are negligible compared to the viscous terms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to think about this which might help.

Imagine you have written down approximate equations of motion for the liquid within, say, a pipe. the equations will contain terms for displacement, velocity, and acceleration. then you take out a red pen and draw a line through the terms that contain velocity, since the creeping flow condition implies almost-zero velocities. Now you can simplify the equations, regroup terms, and take a stab at solving.

This type of simplification is "buried" within the rules for working with similitude parameters (i.e., nondimensional groups) as pointed out by Chet Miller, which is an easier and quicker way to manage problems like this. You'll get the hang of it with a little practice.